# How to restrict data which comes from calling "find" of model in loopback 3 based on acl applied?

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

There are three models in consideration with relevant fields to this question are as below - 
User - id 
Project - id, project_name 
ProjectMember - id, user_id, project_id

When I am calling "find", its listing all the projects which is fine for user who are "admin" but for a "non admin" user, I want to show only their project.

What is the best way to achieve this in loopback 3 ? Do I need to override the "find" or is there any loopback way to do it which I am missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for `before remote` hook:

```
Project.beforeRemote( 'find', function( ctx, next) {
    // here you can modify your query by adding a role based filter to your query
    next();
});
```

Or even better `access` operational hook:

```
Project.observe('access', function( ctx, next) {
    // here you can modify your query by adding a role based filter to your query
    next();
});
```

There you can run additional queries to check if a given user has access to the given project instance.